# How to use an interface within a public interface with a main?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

```
//Program.cs
public interface TestVal
{
    //Input Param 
    string Input { get; }

    //will return output
    TestValRes ValidateRe(string input);
}



class MyClass : ITestVal
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new MyClass();
        instance.Run();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        ValidateRe("test");
    }

    public ITestValRes ValidateRe(string input)
    {
        return null; // return an instance of a class implementing ITestValRes here.
    }
}


//TestvalRes.cs
public interface TestvalRes
{

    string Input { get; }

    bool IsValid { get; }
}
```

So I just want to pass a string to the TestVal, do validation and call TestvalRes to return whether it is Valid or not, and if Invalid, why? So the validation will be done in the first public interface - TestVal, however I still need to call it inside the Main(), right?

Comment: How else would you call it? All you've done is define that anything implementing TestVal will implement a method called `ValidateRe`. You've done nothing more. Also, if you want to follow normal C# naming conventions, I recommend naming your interfaces ITestVal and ITestValRes.

Comment: Lovely, thank you very much. My question is now - how can call TestVal inside the Main method?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd recommend following C# naming conventions and name your interfaces `ITestVal` and `ITestValRes` respectively.

Next, static method cannot call instance methods in the same class (without creating an instance and using that). You need to create an instance of the class and pass control of the application flow to that:

```
class MyClass : ITestVal
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new MyClass();
        instance.Run();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        ValidateRe("test");
    }

    public ITestValRes ValidateRe(string input)
    {
        return null; // return an instance of a class implementing ITestValRes here.
    }
}
```